# Can I create a Derived Type of System.String?

Tags: c#, asmx

In my ASP.NET SOAP Webservice I'm using various string arrays (List) for input parameters, e.g....

```
List<string> CarrierCodes = new List<string>();
```

...but I find it annoying that I cannot give this object a raesonable name, like...

```
List<CarrierCode> CarrierCodes = new List<CarrierCode>();
```

...whereby the CarrierCode object is nothing but a simple System.String

As it's not possible to derive an object from System.String - isn't there any other way to achieve "nice type labels" for such string objects?

Comment: As you said, you cannot derive from string, so you can only create a custom object to store relevant data

Comment: Your field/variable name `CarrierCodes` should be enough to convey that.

Comment: Another `ValueType` (`struct`) with an implicit conversion from `System.String`. It may be needed or not (honestly if it's nothing more than a string I'd think about it) but if you **know** you'll make it more complex then it'll be ready (I'm thinking about `Money` class, for example).

Comment: `I find it annoying` I find it easier to read.

Comment: If Carrier Code isn't going to have any additional functionality, there's no point in creating a new type for it. The variable name CarrierCodes should convey what data it contains sufficiently. If you do need additional functionality, then create a new class or struct to contain that functionality. If it's purely for legibility then you might experiment with enums, but I find them to be more trouble than they're worth when the data might change in the future.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I doubt that the web services framework is going to support that.

Comment: @Servy pretty right if he won't also deploy his assemblies...

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options.

1. Just keep it as-is. Really, if you have a variable called `CarrierCodes`, and it's a `List<string>`, there is nothing wrong with that. It should be plenty descriptive by itself.
2. Make your own class.

   ```
   public class CarrierCode
   {
       public string Code { get; set; }
       //anything else in the future...
   }
   ```

   This is handy if you want to add additional things later on.
3. Use a type alias

   ```
   using CarrierCode = System.String;
   ```

   Be warned, this will be effective throughout the entire file. This is possible, but not suggested on very simple types. Save it for the super-complex data types you don't feel like typing over and over.

Comment: That's more than a couple... Just kidding

Comment: The Type Alias is basically what I'm looking for and it works and looks great in code behind - but in the WSDL the CarrierCode still shows up as string. I'm afraid I'm stuck to use a List<string> when it's about a SOAP Service...

Comment: An alias is what _your program_ calls a type. It's not external.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a type to say something specific then make it non generic:

```
public class CarrierCodeCollection: Collection<String>
{
  <constructor implementations here>
}
```

Then you would have no doubt that you are working with a collection of CarrierCodes. The drawback here is that you would have to implement a collection class for each entity, even though they may all be just plain old strings.

Comment: That won't have any effect on the generated WSDL, so it will have no effect on the clients consuming it.